# ¿Cómo llevar consultas (case, join) de sql server a eloquent de laravel?

Tags: laravel, sql-server, laravel-5, join

tengo un problema con respecto al llevar consultas del tipo CASE y join de sql server a eloquent de laravel, por ejemplo:

En el siguiente ejemplo según el código de proveedor  devuelvo en una nueva columna (stado) los valores de (carga lista) y (carga no lista) dependiendo del valor de la columna estado del modelo Liquidaciones.

```
>>> $liq=IMSUR\Liquidaciones::where('cod_proveedor','6869')->selectRaw("cod_liqu
idacion,cod_proveedor, CASE estado WHEN 'SI' THEN 'carga lista' ELSE 'carga no l
ista' END AS stado")->get();
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#754
     all: [
       IMSUR\Liquidaciones {#755
         cod_liquidacion: "631819",
         cod_proveedor: 6869,
         stado: "carga lista",
       },
       IMSUR\Liquidaciones {#756
         cod_liquidacion: "639519",
         cod_proveedor: 6869,
         stado: "carga lista",
       },
       IMSUR\Liquidaciones {#772
         cod_liquidacion: "35420",
         cod_proveedor: 6869,
         stado: "carga no lista",
       },
     ],
   }
```

Ahora el problema que tengo es al momento de realizar la misma consulta pero agregando atributos de otros modelos por ejemplo:

Seleccionar los atributos cod_liquidacion del modelo Liquidaciones, proveedor del modelo Proveedores y el atributo leyes_imsur del modelo Liquidaciones_laboratorio, además de agregar una columna con el nombre (stado) en donde se indique (carga lista si el valor de leyes_imsur del modelo Liquidaciones_laboratorio es igual a SI)).

Realicé la siguiente consulta con el uso de tinker pero me da el siguiente error:

```
   >>> $li=IMSUR\Liquidaciones::with(['liqui_lab','proveedor_p'])->where('cod_prove
edor','6869')->selectRaw("cod_liquidacion, proveedor_p.proveedor , CASE liqui_la
b.leyes_imsur when 'SI' THEN 'carga lista' ELSE 'no no lista' END AS stado")->ge
t();


Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not fou
nd: 1054 Unknown column 'proveedor_p.proveedor' in 'field list' (SQL: select cod
_liquidacion, proveedor_p.proveedor , CASE liqui_lab.leyes_imsur when 'SI' THEN
'carga lista' ELSE 'no no lista' END AS stado from `liquidaciones` where `cod_pr
oveedor` = 6869)'
```

Mi pregunta es cómo poder realizar  dicha consulta, y en que parte de lo que realice esta el error, gracias.

Dejo aquí, mis modelos relacionados:

modelo Liquidaciones

```
class Liquidaciones extends Model
{
    protected $table='liquidaciones';
    protected $primaryKey = 'cod_liquidacion';
    protected $fillable = ['cod_columna',
                           'cod_liquidacion',
                           'clave_muestra',
                           'fecha_ingreso',
                           'fecha_liquidacion',
                           'cod_proveedor',
                           'particula',
                           'cod_cooperativa',
                           'cod_transportista',
                           'observaciones',
                           'cod_origen',
                           'cheque',
                           'anticipo_',
                           'cheque_',
                           'trans_1',
                           'TMB',
                           'TARA',
                           'HUM',
                           'TMH',
                           'TMS',
                           'IMSUR_ZN',
                           'ZINC',
                           'IMSUR_DM',
                           'PLATA_DM',
                           'IMSUR_PLOMO',
                           'PLOMO',
                           'CLIENTE_ZN',
                           'PRECIO_ZN',
                           'CLIENTE_DM',
                           'PRECIO_AG',
                           'CLIENTE_PLOMO',
                           'PRECIO_PLOMO',
                           'monto',
                           'mas_transporte',
                           'importe_total',
                           'estado',
                           'debe',
                           'cod_grupo_liquidacion',
                           'usuario_ingreso',
                           'usuario_liquidacion',
                           'costo_dolar',
                           'plataforma',
                           'triturado',
                           'pago_transporte',
                           'cod_persona',
                           'devuelto'];
      public function proveedor_p(){
           return $this->belongsTo('IMSUR\Proveedores','cod_proveedor');
      }

      public function liqui_lab(){
      return $this->hasMany('IMSUR\Liquidaciones_laboratorio','cod_liquidacion');
    }
```

modelo Proveedores

```
class Proveedores extends Model
{
    protected $table='proveedores';
    protected $primaryKey = 'cod_proveedor';
    protected $fillable=['cod_proveedor',
                         'proveedor',
                         'cod_cooperativa',
                         'cod_origen'];

    public function liqui_p(){
      return $this->hasMany('IMSUR\Liquidaciones','cod_proveedor');
    }
}
```

Modelo Liquidaciones_laboratorio

```
class Liquidaciones_laboratorio extends Model
{
    protected $table='liquidaciones_laboratorio';
    protected $primaryKey='cod_liquidacion_laboratorio';
    protected $fillable=['cod_liquidacion_laboratorio',
                         'cod_liquidacion',
                         'entregado_laboratorio',
                         'fecha_entregado',
                         'usuario_entregado',
                         'leyes_imsur',
                         'fecha_leyes_imsur',
                         'usuario_leyes_imsur'];

    public function lab_l(){
      return $this->belongsTo('IMSUR\Liquidaciones','cod_liquidacion');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

La forma correcta puede ser de dos maneras (incluso más):

1. Teniendo en cuenta que se está cargando la relación `proveedor_p` con Eager Loading, no es (o no debería ser) necesario cargar dicho campo de esa manera, por lo cual, lo puedes retirar de la consulta, y cargarlo cuando lo necesites de la relación:

   ```
   $li=IMSUR\Liquidaciones::with(['liqui_lab','proveedor_p'])
   ->where('cod_proveedor','6869')
   ->selectRaw("cod_liquidacion, CASE liqui_lab.leyes_imsur when 'SI' THEN 'carga lista' ELSE 'no no lista' END AS stado")
   ->get();
   ```

   Para cargar dicho campo, harías algo así: `$li->proveedor_p->proveedor`
2. La otra opción, en caso que definitivamente no quieras cargarlo con la relación, o que desees tener el resultado directamente en el «primer nivel», sería escribir TODA la consulta en modo *raw* y pasarla por selectRaw() desde el Query builder, sin usar eloquent. Con este método, no podrías cargar relaciones de las bases de datos posteriormente.

Comment: lo realize como esta en tu respuesta pero aun me sale el mismo error

Comment: >>> $li=IMSUR\Liquidaciones::with(['liqui_lab','proveedor_p'])->where('cod_prove
edor','6869')->selectRaw("cod_liquidacion, CASE liqui_lab.leyes_imsur WHEN 'SI'
THEN 'cargas lista' ELSE 'no lista' END AS stado")->get();

Comment: Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not fou
nd: 1054 Unknown column 'liqui_lab.leyes_imsur' in 'field list' (SQL: select cod
_liquidacion, CASE liqui_lab.leyes_imsur WHEN 'SI' THEN 'cargas lista' ELSE 'no
lista' END AS stado from `liquidaciones` where `cod_proveedor` = 6869)'

Comment: Si te fijas, es un problema similar a lo que planteo en mi solución. Si te das cuenta, tendrías que replantear la forma como haces la consulta, o utilizar el segundo método.